# CryptoJS cannot use just AES without error

Tags: javascript

I have a gulpfile that concatenates my dependencies, to make one file.

The final output file has CryptoJS in it. If I use the entire library:
`node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js`

I am able to encrypt data:

```
async function save(data) {
    let saveData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, 'My Secret').toString();
}
```

If I only use parts of the library I need which is just `AES`, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

The files that I am concatenating are in this order:

```
let fileList = [
  'node_modules/crypto-js/core.js',
  'node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js',
  'node_modules/crypto-js/enc-utf8.js',
  'node_modules/crypto-js/aes.js',
]
```

Am I missing a file?

**Edit**

Error stack:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at Object.execute (gamesmart.js:2067)
    at Object.encrypt (gamesmart.js:2114)
    at Object.encrypt (gamesmart.js:1493)
    at Object.<anonymous> (gamesmart.js:42)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at gamesmart.js:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (gamesmart.js:3)
    at Object.save (gamesmart.js:41)
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (ajax.js:3)
execute @   gamesmart.js:2067
encrypt @   gamesmart.js:2114
encrypt @   gamesmart.js:1493
(anonymous) @   gamesmart.js:42
(anonymous) @   gamesmart.js:7
__awaiter   @   gamesmart.js:3
save    @   gamesmart.js:41
document.addEventListener   @   ajax.js:3
async function (async)      
document.addEventListener
```

It is in this function (from the core not mine) (`var key = EvpKDF.create({ keySize: keySize + ivSize }).compute(password, salt)`):

```
execute: function (password, keySize, ivSize, salt) {
            // Generate random salt
            if (!salt) {
                salt = WordArray.random(64/8);
            }

            // Derive key and IV
            var key = EvpKDF.create({ keySize: keySize + ivSize }).compute(password, salt);

            // Separate key and IV
            var iv = WordArray.create(key.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
            key.sigBytes = keySize * 4;

            // Return params
            return CipherParams.create({ key: key, iv: iv, salt: salt });
        }
```

Comment: looks kinda valid... Do you have a full error stack?

Comment: I updated the answer with more information

Comment: could `EvpKDF` be a part of `crypto-js/evpkdf` which is not imported? Looks like `EvpKDF` is `undefined` if I treat the errorstack right

Comment: I added it after `cipher-core` and it still gives me the same error

Comment: look at its source: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/evpkdf.js : I guess you need to run it as `CryptoJS.EvpKDF`. `EvpKDF` 'as it is' is not exported globally

Comment: The core creates var shortcuts, and it is making `var EvpKDF = CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF` https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/a5214c4886c2c921827a3faf4a06c58dd4cb81d4/src/cipher-core.js#L15

Comment: you are so right, for some reason I though you posted your code, but it's a part of a core... That's anyway strange because the `EvpKDF` is still undefined. I think from this moment on you are alone with debugging, I don't think I can help you elsehow...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it in browser? node or where?

I think is related to the code wrapping you have in each file:

```
;(function (root, factory, undef) {
    if (typeof exports === "object") {
        // CommonJS
        // No good for simple concatenation
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        // No good for simple concatenation
    }
    else {
        // Global (browser)
        // Should work
    }
}(this, function (CryptoJS) {  }));
```

I think would be better if you use something like [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) o similar to merge the files.

Or you have to be sure "exports" and "define" are not defined or defined to something different than object and function.